# Render a nested array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I map through multiple objects.
    `[{name:"y", country:"US", cities:[obj,obj,ob]},{name:"y", country:"US", cities:[obj,obj,ob]}]`

How can I nest a loop so I first iterate through the objects and then iterate through (in this example) cities?Thanks!!

my render function without the nested look looks like this :

```
render() {
  const persons = this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5> {item.name} </h5> 
        <h5> {item.country} </h5> 
        //here I would like to show the cities
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div className = "panel-list"> 
        All: {persons} 
      </div> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cities object example:

```
[{visitors:34, rating:4}, 
 {visitors:1234, rating:1},
 {visitors:124, rating:2}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make use of nested map to map over the inner child objects as well like

```
     render() {
            const persons = this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                   <div>
                      <h5> {item.name} </h5> 
                      <h5> {item.country} </h5> 
                      <h4>{item.cities.map((city) => {
                             return (<li>{/* city object details here*/}</li>)
                       })}</h4>
                   </div>);
            });
            return (
            <div>
                <div className = "panel-list"> 
                    All: {persons} 
                </div> 
            </div>
              );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use your solution, i get wrong results. Lets say I (as an example) 5 countries. Each country has 5 cities. Then I would get France plus all cities for all 5 countries instead of just one

Comment: As I under from your data object `{name:"y", country:"US", cities:[obj,obj,ob]}` cities is cities within country US, Is it? How does your cities object look like. I suppose you  need to add that in your question as well

Comment: I edited my question with the countries object. so if I would do <h4>{city.visitor}</h4> I would not get that per country, but it would look like France, (visitor) 34,1234,124

Comment: In your question, the object contains name country and cities but not countries See `{name:"y", country:"US", cities:[obj,obj,ob]}`

Comment: sorry it was a type-meant cities not countries

Comment: @javascripting, How do you know which ratings are for which city? There is no city name associated with a rating?

Comment: I provided sample data and got super confuses and mixed up everything. Your answer is great and I just mixed up what properties those objects have. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem, I would say if your case is that you have a city with a rating, you might need to restructure your data a bit so that the corresponsing city visitors are in the desired object